# Spring boot - unable to use web.xml with WAR deployment

Tags: spring, spring-boot, web.xml

I am not able to use web.xml with spring boot in war deployment.

I am aware that there are ways of converting web.xml using @Configuration, but I must stick with web.xml for now. I was following the official document, here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file-for-older-containers

I was able to deploy my application in WAR file, but it was not using web.xml.

Maybe I am not following the step 85.2 correctly, as I am not sure what it means by "load an applicationContext via a DispatcherServlet":

> 85.2 Create a deployable war file for older servlet containers
>
> Older Servlet containers don’t have support for the
> ServletContextInitializer bootstrap process used in Servlet 3.0. You
> can still use Spring and Spring Boot in these containers but you are
> going to need to add a web.xml to your application and configure it to
> load an ***ApplicationContext*** via a ***DispatcherServlet***.

Can you guide me or point me to any examples or working sample project using web.xml in spring boot?  I am using weblogic server.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the reason to use web.xml?

Comment: BTW at section 85.5 there's an example of traditional web.xml configuration with DispatcherServlet.